# Extension of a derivation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, banach-algebras

Let I be a closed left ideal of a Banach algebra A and let D:I\to I* be a derivation. Does D extend to a derivation from A to A*?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of retagging your question since the tags you chose are not really relevant

Comment: Have you tried looking for possible counterexamples when $A=M_2$ and $I$ is the left ideal generated by the matrix unit $E_{11}\in M_2$?